# Transition Matrix of M/M/1 Queue

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process, queueing-theory

We know that for an M/M/1 queue the state space is $S=\{0,1,2,... \}$. Further the probability to go from state $i$ to $i+1$ is $\lambda$ for all $i$ in $S$. Moreover, to go from $i$ to $i-1$ is the probability $\mu$ $\forall i \in S$.

So one can draw the following picture, taken from the [wikipedia page on M/M/1 queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue):

[image]

Now with this, one can establish the transition matrix:

$T=$\begin{pmatrix}
1-\lambda & \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
\mu & 1-(\mu+ \lambda) & \lambda & 0 & 0 & ... \\
0 & \mu & 1-(\mu+\lambda) & \lambda & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 &  \mu & 1-(\mu+\lambda) & \lambda & ...\\
&&&&&...
\end{pmatrix}

I know that the transition rate matrix is given by:

$M=$\begin{pmatrix}
-\lambda & \lambda & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
\mu & -(\mu+ \lambda) & \lambda & 0 & 0 & ... \\
0 & \mu & -(\mu+\lambda) & \lambda & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 &  \mu & -(\mu+\lambda) & \lambda & ...\\
&&&&&...
\end{pmatrix}

How can I get from the transition matrix to the transition rate matrix? Is it even possible?

I appreciate any help! Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry but what on Earth is the matrix $T$ supposed to represent in your view?

Comment: It represents the probabilites to go from a state to another. Since going from state $0$ to $1$ is given by $\lambda$, and it is not possible that 2 customers leaves the system, $p_{00}$ has to be equal $1-\lambda.$

Comment: Not at all. Values of $\lambda$ greater than $1$ are common, which could make you think. Actually you might be confusing (badly) the discrete time setting and the continuous time setting.

Comment: yes you are totally right... I confused them. I only had discrete markov chains in school. But why is there no transition matrix for the countinous case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More generally... one may want to keep in mind that Markov chains (in discrete time) and Markov processes (in continuous time) are different (although related) objects.

**1.** A Markov chain $(X_n)$, indexed by $n$ integer, is described by a transition matrix $P$, such that, for every states $(x,y)$ and every $n$, $$\Pr(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n=x)=P_{xy}.$$ Thus:

> The matrix $P$ has nonnegative entries and every row sum $\sum\limits_yP_{xy}$ is $1$.

The powers of the matrix $P$ yield the transition probabilities of the chain in any number of steps, through the identities

> $$\Pr(X_{n+k}=y\mid X_n=x)=(P^k)_{xy}.$$

**2.** A Markov process $(Y_t)$, indexed by $t$ real, is described by a transition rate matrix $Q$, often called its generator, such that, informally, for every states $x\ne y$, when $\mathrm dt\to0^+$, $$\Pr(X_{t+\mathrm dt}=y\mid X_t=x)=Q_{xy}\mathrm dt+o(\mathrm dt).$$ Additionally, the diagonal entries are defined as $$Q_{xx}=-\sum_yQ_{xy}.$$
Thus:

> The offdiagonal entries of the matrix $Q$ are nonnegative and every row sum $\sum\limits_yQ_{xy}$ is $0$.

The matrix $Q$ yields the transition probabilities of the process, through the identities

> $$\Pr(X_{t+s}=y\mid X_t=x)=(\mathrm e^{sQ})_{xy},$$

for every nonnegative $(t,s)$, where the exponential is defined by the usual series, always convergent, that is, $$\mathrm e^{sQ}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{s^n}{n!}Q^n.$$

**3.** Every Markov process gives rise to some Markov chains, usually called *embedded* chains, by discretizations of the time. That is, if $(Y_t)$ is a Markov process with generator $Q$ , then for each $\tau\gt0$, $(X_n)$ defined by $$X_n=Y_{n\tau},$$ is a Markov chain with transition matrix $$P=\mathrm e^{\tau Q}.$$ (*Exercise: Show that if $Q$ is a generator, that is, with nonnegative offdiagonal entries and every row sum equal to $0$, then $\mathrm e^{\tau Q}$ is a transition matrix, that is, with nonnegative entries and every row sum equal to $1$.*)

**4.** In the other direction, not every Markov chain corresponds to the discretization of a Markov process. The ones that do are called *embeddable*.

(*Exercise: Find some non embeddable transition matrix $P$. Hint: Two states are enough, and watch out for the zero entries of $P$*.)

**5.** Queues in general, and M/M/1 queues in particular, are Markov processes (in continuous time), as explained on the WP page the OP links to. As such, they can be discretized into Markov chains (in discrete time).

**Nota:** All this can be made rigorous on every finite state space, always, and on countable state spaces, under some technical additional conditions that we left out (and that are satisfied for the queues the OP is interested in).

Comment: This is great!! thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

The transition rate matrix is another name for the generator matrix for a continuous time markov chain.

A transition matrix is for a discrete time markov chain.

$M$ would be for a continuous time markov chain (the underlying process for the queue is based on Poisson processes) while $T$ would be for a discrete time markov chain (the underlying process for the queue is based on Bernoulli processes).

Answer (score -2):

The matrix is wrong. It should read "1-$\lambda$" instead

Also for the other probabilities it is not $-(\mu + \lambda)$ but rather $1-(\mu + \lambda)$
as probabilities can't be negative, also it's pretty clear by the picture you posted.

Comment: Thank you so far. I just realized that I always read it wrong. $M$ is not the transition matrix, it is the transition rare matrix. I never heard of that before...

Comment: transtition RATE matrix... I edited my post.

Comment: Sorry but the quantity $1-(\lambda+\mu)$ is simply irrelevant to the model (fortunately, since it can well be negative). All in all, I fail to see how this answer can help the OP to reach a clear view of the situation (and don't get me started on answers accepted 28 minutes after they are posted...).

Comment: I don't get your problem. The quantitiy $1-(\lambda+\mu)$ is everything BUT irrelevant for this question and I also don't see how it could possible become negative as they clearly add up to 1 (just look at the picture...) maybe you should also take a little more time to think about comments

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue

Comment: given the information that the matrix should only contain the parameters of the exponentioal distribution-i.e. if you want the transition rate matrix- this is true. But mr_T was asking for the transition matrix.